# audio_common - sound_play error "playbin" not found

Tags: ros, audio-common, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to make text to speech work on the raspberry.

I use groovy and after copying the "sound_play" folder from the "audio_common" package from github and using catkin_make, it basically works. But when sending the command "rosrun sound_play say.py 'text' " I get the following error from soundplay_node.py:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1393587210.981293] sound_play node is ready to play sound
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1393587241.765914] Exception in callback: playbin
[INFO] [WallTime: 1393587241.789185] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ros/src/sound_play/scripts/soundplay_node.py", line 217, in callback
    self.voicesounds[data.arg] = soundtype(wavfilename)
  File "/home/pi/ros/src/sound_play/scripts/soundplay_node.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.sound = gst.element_factory_make("playbin","player")
ElementNotFoundError: playbin
```

Can anyone help me in solving this problem?

**Background Info:**
Same problem is reported here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5114
Seems that the programmers from PR2 also had the same error but did not poste how to solve it: https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/issues/5
Note: I use the "hydro" version of sound_play, as groovy version is not working due to a bug (see https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/issues/24).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134311/audio_common---sound_play-error-%22playbin%22-not-found/) by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If my memory is correct, this is happening because you don't have the proper gstreamer plugins installed.

Can you confirm that you have the libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-good and python-gst packages installed?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2014-02-28**:
Thanks for your quick support! I have newer versions of the plugins installed, however some dependency problems in general... I'm just trying to set up raspbian and ros completely new and will use the old 0.10 versions, hope it will work then, I will report here.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-28**:
My observation has been that the 1.0 and 0.10 versions of the gstreamer plugins can be installed side-by-side without too much trouble, and they're packaged with the major version number in the package name to facilitate this.

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2014-03-02**:
After re-installing raspbian & ros & all needed packages it's working now :-)! Thanks for your help!!